# Why doesn't my date validation code work?

Tags: java, date

my code doesn't return any value and i have no idea why. My assignment requires me to write a code that accepts date in mm/dd/yyyy format and im required to put leap year in. The problem is, i dont get back any input. Im an amateur ad i dont know what is wrong. Im also allowed to use Case statment but I'm not sure how to implement case.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Question1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("/");
        System.out.println("Please enter a date in mm/dd/yyyy format: ");
        String mm = sc.next();
        String dd = sc.next();
        String yyyy = sc.next();
        int month = Integer.parseInt(mm);
        int day = Integer.parseInt(dd);
        int year = Integer.parseInt(yyyy);

        if (month <= 0 || month>12)
        {
            System.out.println("invalid month ");
        }
        if (year%4 != 0 || month == 02 || day >= 29)
        {
           System.out.println("invalid date");
        } 
        if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11 || day >= 31)
        {
           System.out.println("Invalid day");
        }
        if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12 || day >=32 )
        {
           System.out.println("Invalid day");
        }
        else
        {
           System.out.println("Valid date");
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: So, `year` not divisible by 4 is always "invalid date"? Really? Sure you didn't mean `&&` instead of `||`? In many of those checks? You do know the difference, right?

Comment: Fixed it and still no output. whats wrong now?

Comment: @BamdadGoudarziMoazami your code doesn't return any value because the method is void. What are you trying to return? Perhaps you could post the entire assignment requirements I'm having a hard time understanding what your goal is

Comment: @kalenpw - In context, he obviously meant output - see all the `System.out.println()` statements.  @Andreas Yeah, his logic is wrong - that's probably because it becomes hard to debug when the code never gets past the second line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code sets the delimiter to `/`.  Then you enter something like `12/25/2016`.  The first `sc.next()` call gets the 12.  The second one gets the 25.  The third... waits, because it doesn't see another `/` so it doesn't know you're done.  If you typed `12/25/2016/` with your current code, it would at least give output, even if that output isn't correct yet.

Answer (score 0):

you want to use switch case then go through the below code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Question1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("/");

        System.out.println("Please enter a date in mm/dd/yyyy/ format: ");
        String mm = sc.next();
        String dd = sc.next();
        String yyyy = sc.next();
        int month = Integer.parseInt(mm);
        int day = Integer.parseInt(dd);
        int year = Integer.parseInt(yyyy);
        boolean valid = isValidDate(day,month,year);
        if (valid == true)
        {
            System.out.println("Date is Valid");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Date is InValid");
        }
    }
    public static boolean isValidDate(int day, int month ,int year)
    {   
        boolean monthOk = (month >= 1) && (month <= 12);
        boolean dayOk = (day >= 1) && (day <= daysInMonth(year, month));

        return (monthOk && dayOk);
    }
    private static int daysInMonth(int year, int month) {
        int daysInMonth;

    switch (month) {
    case 1: 
    case 3: 
    case 5: 
    case 7: 
    case 8: 
    case 10: // go through
    case 12:
        daysInMonth = 31;
        break;
    case 2:
        if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0)) {
            daysInMonth = 29;
        } else {
            daysInMonth = 28;
        }
        break;
    default:
        // returns 30 even for nonexistant months 
        daysInMonth = 30;
    }
    return daysInMonth;
  }    

}
```

take input as **12/25/2016/**, not this **12/25/2016**.

Comment: This mate. This helped alot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to get you started:

```
    final String DELIMITER = "/";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a date in mm/dd/yyyy format:\n ");

    String date = sc.next();
    sc.close();

    String[] dateParts = date.split(DELIMITER);
    //check : if dateParts size is not 3 ....something is wrong

    String mm = dateParts[0];
    String dd = dateParts[1];
    String yyyy = dateParts[2];

    System.out.println(mm+" "+ dd +" "+ yyyy);
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems you have put else in wrong place. Suppose you second condition is getting correct and all other false, then also your program will show it as valid date and same on the opposite side.
For example, say day is 30 for any date, then it will satisfy second condition and it will show you "Invalid date".

```
You should write if else as follows.
If{
     If{
          If{
            }
       }
}else{
}
```

All if must be in a nested if and then else. Your if else sequence is wrong.

Comment: Besides being incorrectly capitalized and improperly indented, this is wrong.  It will shift the problem instead of solving it.  What happens if that third `if` fails?  It won't hit the `else` block.

Comment: You just need to check that execute 5th condition only if above 4 fails. That's all